# Weird autolayout centering issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

This has been dogging me a bit.

Basically, what it comes down to is that when I manually define autolayout constraints using layout anchors, and use the view controller in a popover, the center is in the wrong place. It's seeming to center around the boundary from the left of the popover pop-out arrow to the left and the right margin, which is not the center of the area of the popover.

This seems to work fine with other UIViewController presentation methods, like UIModalPresentationFormSheet.

Any ideas how I can fix this in a layout-friendly way without special-casing the margins?

PS. The exact same thing happens if you peg the layout to the center of the parent view, it's slightly off.

(note: Edited because I posted the source badly)

```
-(void)loadView {

    // create root view.
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    self.view = view;


    UIView *parentView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [view addSubview:parentView];

    [parentView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [parentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    [parentView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:view.leadingAnchor constant:20.0].active = YES;
    [parentView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:view.trailingAnchor constant:-20.0].active = YES;

   [parentView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:view.topAnchor constant:10.0].active = YES;
    [parentView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:view.bottomAnchor constant:-10.0].active = YES;
}
```

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Your constraints are insufficient. Is this real code?

Comment: sorry, bad cut/paste job. These constraints should be sufficient, and as I stated, it works fine for a page sheet or other presentations, just not for a popover presentation.

Comment: So I guess the question now is simply where the edges of the view are. You assume they are the edges of the main area. But maybe they include the arrow. If the arrow is just a mask that would help explain it.

Comment: Correct, it seems to be centering as if the arrow is part of the view. I'm just not sure how to fix it cleanly, in a way that the view can be presented both as a popover and modal overlay, at least without conditionally modifying constraints.

Comment: Pin to the view's _margins_, not to its _edges_. This is why margins were invented.

Answer (score 1):

The *edges* of the view are not where you think they are; the leading edge is where the *point of the arrow* is, not where the side of the visible rectangle is.

However, the *margins* are where you expect them. So pin to the `layoutMarginsGuide` instead, and all will be well. Indeed, this is one of the things margins are intended to cover.

In Swift:

```
parentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(
    equalTo: self.view.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor, constant:0).isActive = true
parentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(
    equalTo: self.view.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor, constant:0).isActive = true
```

(And change those `constant` numbers as you see fit.)

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you. This also explains why my NIBs largely work, since the layout guid floats around fairly obviously. It hadn't occurred to me that I would have to do this when there wasn't a nib.